# how to fix Null output in an OCR flutter app?

Tags: flutter

am new to flutter , here is the main code for an OCR app the normally extracts text from image and display the text on the app and  also store it in a file , the app for now displays error "Extracted Text Error: type Null is not a subtype of type Iterable-dynamic." in the app and no  file is created [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21nyg.png)

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter_tesseract_ocr/flutter_tesseract_ocr.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  String extractedText = '';

  Future<void> _getImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (pickedFile != null) {
      String extractedText = await extractTextFromImage(pickedFile.path);

      // Check if extractedText is null or empty
      if (extractedText != null && extractedText.isNotEmpty) {
        // Get the documents directory using path_provider
        Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        String filePath = '${documentsDirectory.path}/OCR.txt';

        // Save text to file
        await saveTextToFile(extractedText, filePath);

        setState(() {
          this.extractedText = extractedText;
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          this.extractedText = 'No text extracted from the image.';
        });
      }
    }
  }


  Future<String> extractTextFromImage(String imagePath) async {
    try {
      String extractedText = await FlutterTesseractOcr.extractText(imagePath);
      return extractedText;
    } catch (e) {
      return 'Error: $e';
    }
  }

  Future<void> saveTextToFile(String text, String filePath) async {
    final file = File(filePath);
    await file.writeAsString(text);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('OCR Text Extractor'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _getImage,
              child: Text('Capture or Upload Image'),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Text('Extracted Text: $extractedText'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

normally the app displays the text and stores it in a text file also

Comment: The problem is in the `FlutterTesseractOcr.extractText(imagePath)` method, in `catch(e){...}` add the second parameter `catch(e, stackTrace){...}` and print the `stackTrace` parameter to indicate on which line the problem occurs and attach your question. If this method is from a package, open an issue in its repository.